# Huffman encoding in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, huffman-code, bit-fields

I want to use a huffman code in a client server socket program written in C

So i've written a code for producing a huffman tree from a text file as the input.
 However, I cant figure out how to use it in a client server socket program.
SO far I have considered the following approaches--
1) send the encoded file in form of bits through the socket connection. Cant do that since i am using C language and there is no bit data type( i doubt there is a bit data type in any language for that matter).
2)Send the data in form of integer 0s and 1s. That will totally defeat the purpose. Char(1 byte) Int(4 bytes at least)

Comment: This is not really related to huffman-encoding  but is essentially asking how to send binary data over a socket. Therefore it is a duplicate of [Send raw binary data over C socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996657/send-raw-binary-data-over-c-socket). And about how to pack bits to bytes see [Bits to Byte in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317130/bits-to-byte-in-c).

Comment: You could start by writing your data to a file and then reading it back. Once you can do that, then start thinking how to use a socket instead of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pack your bits into bytes and you are done. This is a quite trivial task by using bitwise operators. Eg

```
uint32_t value = 0;

value |= 1 << 3; // set fourth bit to one
bool isFourthBitSet = value & (1 << 4); // check if fifth bit is set
```

You could also use a bit packet struct, something like

```
union compressed_byte {
 struct {
   uint8_t b0 : 1;
   uint8_t b1 : 1;
   ..
 }
 uint8_t raw;
}
```

To make all these operations transparent to the user. Of course you must ensure that both client and socket use the same memory layout. In addition, if you are packing into units larger than 1 byte you must also ensure same endianness.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pack the bits into bytes yourselves. This is not specific to C - very few languages have a bit data type.

You need to "save up" 8 bits, then convert them into a byte, then send the byte. Approximately like this:

```
int bitBuffer = 0;
int numberOfSavedBits = 0;

// bit must be 1 or 0
void sendBit(int bit) {
    bitBuffer |= (bit << numberOfSavedBits);
    numberOfSavedBits++;
    if (numberOfSavedBits == 8) {
        sendByte(bitBuffer);
        numberOfSavedBits = 0;
        bitBuffer = 0;
    }
}
```

You also need to do the opposite conversion when receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your `0` and `1` values and pack them into the bits of a `char` array.

For example, suppose you had the following array of 16 `int` values:

```
  [0]  [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]  [6]  [7]  [8]  [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You could compress this into 2 `char` values with the following binary format:

```
    [0]        [1]
-----------------------
| 01011101 | 00100011 |
-----------------------
```

On the sender side you can pack the bits like this:

```
int encodedValues[1024];
...
// set encodedValues
...
char packedValues[128] = {0};
int i;
for (i=0; i<1024; i++) {
    if (encodedValues[i]) {
        packedValues[i/8] |= (1 << (i % 8));
    }
}
```

Then on the other side, you unpack them:

```
char packedValues[128];
...
// receive packedValues
...
int encodedValues[1024] = {0};
for (i=0; i<1024; i++) {
    encodedValues[i] = ((packedValues[i/8] & (1 << (i % 8))) != 0);
}
```