# how to send binary data through socket in c?

Tags: c, sockets, send

I'm trying to send binary data to the client, what I'm trying to do is:
`write(client_fd,"0xf",size,flag)`. I don't know how to make the string binary and not sure what type of flag should I use.

Comment: When you say you want to send the string as binary, do you mean send `'0'`, `'x'` `'f'`, and `'\0'` or send b1111?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send raw binary data over C socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996657/send-raw-binary-data-over-c-socket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string literal "0xf" is similar to

```
char str[] = { '0', 'x', 'f', '\0' };
```

If you want to write actual 0x0 and 0xf data, hex values can be expressed within a string literal, each with a leading `\x` like this:

```
size = 2;
nwritten = write(sock_fd, "\x0\xf", size);
```